# Codegen causal ML inference too short compared to results in model card API

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface

I'm experimenting with the Salesforce/codegen-350M-mono model.

When I generate text using a prompt, the result on my machine is much shorter than what I get inputting the same prompt in the API window of the model card.  On my machine it just adds 'return'

```
import datasets
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

checkpoint = "Salesforce/codegen-350M-mono"
device = "cpu"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint, trust_remote_code=True).to(device)

text = """def round_to_multiple(num, mult):
    \"""Rounds to nearest multiple of another number.\"""
    """
input_ids = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

generated_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
print(tokenizer.decode(generated_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

Here is the output

```
The attention mask and the pad token id were not set. As a consequence, you may observe unexpected behavior. Please pass your input's `attention_mask` to obtain reliable results.
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
def round_to_multiple(num, mult):
    """Rounds to nearest multiple of another number."""
    return
```

When I enter the same prompt in the [model card](https://huggingface.co/Salesforce/codegen-350M-mono?text=def%20round_to_multiple%28num%2C%20mult%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%5C%22%22%22Rounds%20to%20nearest%20multiple%20of%20another%20number.%5C%22%22%22) code-generation window, I get the following:

```
def round_to_multiple(num, mult):
    \"""Rounds to nearest multiple of another number.\"""
    if (num % mult == 0):
        return int(num)
    else:
        return
```

How would I get the result to be the same (or similar but longer) as on the web API?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only generating one token when calling `model.generate()`. You simply need to edit the `max_length` parameters of the `generate()` function:

```
generated_ids = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=128)
```